# Number of rows based on screen orientation JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a webform app in java EE 6 + JSF2, and I want to display it in mobile devices. I made a view for portrait mode, and now I need the landscape version. There are tons of datatables and datagrids, and I want to change the rownum of them based on screen orientation. Is that possible? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not with JSF, as it doesn't run on client, but it's certainly possible with JS and/or CSS.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC ! You have saved me a lot of time! I finally found a solution with CSS and the render attribute of the components.